# Reference label in small caps using cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, small-caps

I am using the `cleveref` package for cross-references in my document. I am using `\cref` throughout my document, so the label is added to the reference. However, I would like the label `Figure` and `Table` to be in small caps shape (`\scshape`?). How can I achieve this?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
        \hline
        0 & 1\\
        1 & 0\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A table}
    \label{tab:example}
\end{table}

Here is a reference: \cref{tab:example}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you just want the label capitalized, or also the reference? The first can be achieved using the options provided by the `caption` package: `\usepackage[labelfont = {sc}]{caption}`

Comment: No, I also want the reference to be in small caps. Since I am using `cref`, the output of `\cref{tab:example}` looks like `Table 1`. There, I want the word `Table` to be in small caps.

Comment: Adding `\Crefformat{figure}{#2{}\scshape{Figure} #1{}#3}` and
`\Crefformat{table}{#2{}\scshape{Table} #1{}#3}` to the preamble seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I found is in two parts:
`\usepackage[labelfont = {sc}]{caption}` capitalizes the label. 
`\Crefformat{figure}{#2{}\scshape{Figure} #1{}#3}` and `\Crefformat{table}{#2{}\scshape{Table} #1{}#3}` the reference. Of course, if you want the same behaviour for equations, sections etc. these have to be added.

Explanation of the arguments of `\Crefformat` from the documentation on ctan:

> It  should  contain  three  arguments, #1, #2 and #3. The  first 
>   argument  is  the  formatted  version  of  the  label  counter  (e.g.
>   \theequation).  The other two are used to mark the beginning and end
>   of the part of the cross-reference that forms the hyperlink when the
>   hyperref package is used, and must appear in that order.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelfont = {sc}]{caption}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\Crefformat{figure}{#2{}\scshape{Figure} #1{}#3}
\Crefformat{table}{#2{}\scshape{Table} #1{}#3}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            \hline
            0 & 1\\
            1 & 0\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{A table}
        \label{tab:example}
    \end{table}

    Here is a reference: \cref{tab:example}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: How would you do it for German? `\Crefformat{Abbildung}{#2{}\scshape{Figure} #1{}#3}` or `\Crefformat{figure}{#2{}\scshape{Abbildung} #1{}#3}`? Or any more elegant solution?

Comment: @thymaro: not sure. I had expected the `cleveref` package to play properly when you set the language to german using `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`, but it doesn't seem to be the case ... depending on what you need to achieve, you could either use the `\autoref` command (provided by `hyperref` package), redefine manually as you suggested ... or find a fix for `cleveref` to work with other languages, but that would best be posted as separate question I think

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I don't actually need to do this, so I'll refrain from posting the question. I was just wondering how this would be achieved and if you already knew a method. As long as noone else is bugged by this, I guess we should let it rest.

Comment: nothing is stopping you from asking a question even if you're not in desperate need for an answer _now_ ;)

Comment: @thymaro: I couldn't let go, and actually it does work also for `cleveref` (of course). You just need to load with the `[ngerman]` option ...