# Cleveref lowercase for single references

Tags: cleveref, capitalization

The `cleveref` has two main citation commands: `\Cref` and `\cref` depending on whether you're referencing in the beginning of the sentence (producing `Figure 1`) or anywhere else (producing the abbreviated form `fig. 1`).
On rare occasions though, one may want to have the "long" label in the middle of a sentence. How can I have that **single** label in lowercase? [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370340/182889) answer makes *all* references in small caps, but I'm looking for a solution to keep the standard as provided by the `cleveref` package, but change it to lowercase ad hoc in some situations.

Ideally I'd like to have a command (say `\smallCref`) producing `figure 1` when needed.

Thanks in advance for any help!

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Foo\label{fig:foo}}
\end{figure}

\Cref{fig:foo} shows a correct usage of \verb|\Cref{}| at the beginning of the sentence. Whereas we can see how to use \verb|\cref{}| at the end of a sentence (\cref{fig:foo}).
\par Sometimes though, one may want to reference \Cref{fig:foo} with the complete label ``figure'', but having it capitalized in the middle of a sentence is weird. How can I have that single reference in smallcaps, leaving all other references in the document in the original capitalization?
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like you want lower case (figure 1) and not smallcaps (ꜰɪɢᴜʀᴇ 1), is that correct?

Comment: That is correct @Marijn sorry I'm not native English speaking and confused small caps with lowercase. I definitely meant lowercase :) I corrected my question

Comment: There are many ways to configure the reference commands provided by `cleveref`, but a quick and dirty hack would be using `\lcnamecref{fig:foo}~\labelcref{fig:foo}`. Maybe somebody comes up with a clean solution, but this will do in the meantime...

Comment: This can be easily turned into a command. It's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: @Superuser27 I made an answer out of it

Comment: @Superuser27 Maybe you could change the title of your question from 'small caps' to 'lowercase'  so others searching for the same thing can find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty hack. Create a new command, that combines `\lcnamecref` and `\labelcref`:

```
\newcommand{\lccref}[1]{\lcnamecref{#1}~\labelcref{#1}}
```

Which will give you the following:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{cleveref}
  \newcommand{\lccref}[1]{\lcnamecref{#1}~\labelcref{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Foo\label{fig:foo}}
\end{figure}

\Cref{fig:foo} shows a correct usage of \verb|\Cref{}| at the beginning of the sentence. Whereas we can see how to use \verb|\cref{}| at the end of a sentence (\cref{fig:foo}).
\par Sometimes though, one may want to reference \lccref{fig:foo} with the complete label ``figure'', but having it capitalized in the middle of a sentence is weird. How can I have that single reference in smallcaps, leaving all other references in the document in the original capitalization?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly fine until I try referencing multiple figures/equations/... at once. I turned it into a new question, maybe you can help me out there as well → https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481335/lcnamerefs-with-multiple-references