# lcnameref(s) with multiple references

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

The `cleveref` manual states (page 7):

> The `\namecrefs` and `\nameCrefs` commands  produce  the  plural  forms.   The `\lcnamecref` and `\lcnamecrefs` commands  force  the  reference  name  to  lowercase,  for  use  when the `capitalise` option  is  enabled. [...] Note that all these commands can only be passed a single reference name; they do not accept multi-references like `\cref`.  (Passing multiple references to these commands  would  make  little  sense  if  the  references  had  different  types,  and  is redundant if they have the same type.)

I am interested in the last part stating that it's "redundant": does that mean there already is a command that does that? Or do they mean one can simply use `\lcnamecrefs` instead of `\lcnamecref` to produce the plural form?

I'm asking because of the answer suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481324/182889): I'm trying to use `\newcommand{\lccref}[1]{\lcnamecref{#1}~\labelcref{#1}}` to automate lowercase referencing but it breaks everytime I have multiple references (obviously, seeing the above bit from the manual, this is a "feature").

How can I change my command to work with both single **and** multiple references?

---

**MWE**:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcommand{\lccref}[1]{\lcnamecref{#1}~\labelcref{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    E=mc^2\label{eq:foo}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    E/m=c^2\label{eq:bar}
\end{equation}

First \lccref{eq:foo}, then \lccref{eq:bar}. But don't try \lccref{eq:foo,eq:bar}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new command `\lccrefs` which passes only the first parameter to `\lcnamecrefs`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{cleveref}
  \newcommand{\lccref}[1]{\lcnamecref{#1}~\labelcref{#1}}
  \makeatletter
      \def\lcfirstnamecrefs#1,#2\@nil{\lcnamecrefs{#1}}
      \newcommand{\lcfirstnamecref}[1]{\lcfirstnamecrefs #1,\@nil}
  \makeatother
  \newcommand{\lccrefs}[1]{\lcfirstnamecref{#1}~\labelcref{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    E=mc^2\label{eq:foo}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  E/m=c^2\label{eq:bar}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 \label{eq:baz}
\end{equation}

    First \lccrefs{eq:foo}, then \lccref{eq:bar}. 
    But don't try \lccrefs{eq:foo,eq:bar} or 
    \lccrefs{eq:foo,eq:bar,eq:baz}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but then the first `\newcommand{\lccref}[1]{\lcnamecref{#1}~\labelcref{#1}}` is no longer needed?

Comment: You need it for the singular, e.g. `\lccref` will print the singular 'equation' and `\lccrefs` the plural 'equations'

Comment: Right, thanks! Is there a way to auto switch within a single command? i.e. `\lccref` outputs `figure xy` if it receives a single parameter, `figures xy and yz` if it receives multiple?

Comment: Also it doesn't work with more than 2 references :(

Comment: I have no problems with more than two references. Maybe you could elaborate a bit on what is wrong

Comment: Not sure what I did wrong but your updated answer definitely works with 2+ references. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `lcnameref`, you can also locally (i.e., within a `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` pair) change the label names with `\crefname`. You need to specify the names for each type of reference separately.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\smallCref}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}%
\crefname{equation}{equation}{equations}%
\cref{#1}%
\endgroup%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Foo\label{fig:foo}}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
    E=mc^2\label{eq:foo}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    E/m=c^2\label{eq:bar}
\end{equation}


\Cref{fig:foo} shows a correct usage of \verb|\Cref{}| at the beginning of the sentence. Whereas we can see how to use \verb|\cref{}| at the end of a sentence (\cref{fig:foo}).
\par Sometimes though, one may want to reference \Cref{fig:foo} with the complete label ``figure'', but having it capitalized in the middle of a sentence is weird. How can I have that single reference in smallcaps, leaving all other references in the document in the original capitalization?

In lower case: \smallCref{fig:foo}. Abbreviated: \cref{fig:foo}.

First \smallCref{eq:foo}, then \smallCref{eq:bar}. But don't try \smallCref{eq:foo,eq:bar}.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The answer if perfectly valid, but @DG's answer doesn't require to redefine the name for each environment one wants to reference (figure/table/section/chapter/equation/...), although yours is more straight forward, his is more flexible in my opinion, so I'm going to "accept" his. But still thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @Superuser27 I see you changed your mind? Note that, if you don't want the abbreviated labels at all in your document, it is much easier to use `\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}` (but I assume you knew that already).